# Reliably handling date time in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, i am using firebase realtime db and firebase functions as triggers.

Our application stores daily analytics numbers. For example total messages that got sent today. So, in firebase DB we create a node with the timestamp as the beginning of the day. the code to calculate that looks like below:

```
function findDayBegninning(date:any){
    const ms = date.getTime();
    const msPerDay = 86400 * 1000;
    return  ms - (ms % msPerDay);
}
```

The problem is that we do not know how to align it to a particular timezone. For example with the current behavior, the timestamp coming up is

1561075200000

which in GMT timezone shows as Thursday, June 20, 2019 5:00:00 PM.

So, basically in my timezone the day is considered as beginning at 5PM every day. Which is a problem clearly as i need it to be 12am (midnight).

So, how to handle this? Simply add  (7*60*60*1000) to it ?

I am afraid doing this then will make it wrong for some other timezone daily stat

Comment: JavaScript integer timestamps are canonically UTC. You should store and treat them as if they are in the UTC time zone and convert them to a local time zone in the client or server code that is consuming them.

Comment: well the above code is on server side and as is then it should be correct as getTime will give time in UTC.  but that make a day ending every day 5pm as per CA timezone.

Comment: Days are not all 24 hrs long in places where daylight saving is observed. And offsets change from time to time so yes, you must accomodate the offset for each place with a different offset, plus historical changes to offsets and DST observance. Consider using a library that includes timezone functions (probably leveraging the IANA timezone database), writing all that yourself is a significant undertaking.